# "Member Mapping specified is not valid" error when saving to a database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

The full error message is below:

> (46,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'SEJ_STARDATE' in type 'HotelSearch.APP_SEJOUR' is not
>   compatible with
>   'SqlServer.date[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member
>   'SEJ_STARDATE' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.APP_SEJOUR'. (47,12) :
>   error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'SEJ_ENDDATE' in type 'HotelSearch.APP_SEJOUR' is not
>   compatible with
>   'SqlServer.date[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member
>   'SEJ_ENDDATE' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.APP_SEJOUR'. (112,12) :
>   error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'PRIX_PRICE' in type 'HotelSearch.RFS_PRIX_R' is not
>   compatible with
>   'SqlServer.date[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member
>   'PRIX_PRICE' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.RFS_PRIX_R'.

The code is below:

```
var h = new Hotel();

var t = new APP_STAR {
            STA_IDSTAR = 11111,
            STA_STARRATING = "blah",
         };
h.APP_STAR.Add(t);
h.SaveChanges();
```

Obviously this is just dummy data for testing. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to fix this error?

Comment: What is your code producing this message?

Comment: please share some code where this exception is thrown

Comment: you likely changed your database without refreshing your member mapping. or the database you are using is not synchronized with changes , somehow otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
The type 'Edm.String' of member 'SEJ_STARDATE' in type 'HotelSearch.APP_SEJOUR' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.date
```

Change edm.String to a recognizable datetime format (MM/DD/YYYY) by manipulating its contents or using DateTime.Parse